# Databinding error - Could not find accessor

Tags: android, android-databinding

I googled but still didn't find solution for me.

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import
            alias="noteViewModel"
            type="com.app.screen.createnote.CreateNoteViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etNote"
                style="@style/JWidget.EditText.Grey"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:text="@={noteViewModel.note.description}" />        
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

This is my ViewModel code:

```
public class CreateNoteViewModel extends BaseObservable {
     private Note note;
     @Bindable
     public Note getNote() {
         return note;
     }

     public void setNote(Note note) {
         this.note = note;
         notifyPropertyChanged(BR.note);
     }
```

}

But when I try run my app I got it:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Could not find accessor com.justsafe.tmgr.justsafe.screen.createnote.CreateNoteViewModel.note
>   file:C:\android\work\JustSafeTmgr\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_create_note.xml
>   loc:44:33 - 44:62
>   ****\ data binding error ****

P.S. In other place in my app it work, but there I get problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change the `<import>` tag to a `<variable>` tag:

```
<data>
        <variable
            name="noteViewModel"
            type="com.app.screen.createnote.CreateNoteViewModel" />
    </data>
```

Comment: i m already using `variable` tag but still getting `****/ data binding error ****msg:Could not find accessor` error @LuizFernandoSalvaterra

Comment: could you please ask in another question?

Comment: @Ravi Vaniya, if you have already given variable tag instead of import as you said. Now Please make sure you have given 'getter' and 'setter' methods for all the variables in your 'Model Class'. This may solve your problem.