# How can I fix the below error in databinding?

Tags: android

```
I am using one Pojo and I am getting databinding error 

Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Could not find accessor com.jmr.agency.banking.data.db.communication.CommTransaction.dName
file:C:\Users\1432\Documents\Pooja\my_proj\Aman_bank300719\Agency_Banking_Rewamp\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_receive_money_security_task.xml
loc:183:68 - 183:87
****\ data binding error ****

this is my code
ActivityReceiveMoneySecurityTaskBinding binding;

this is my xml
`<data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />
<variable
            name="security_check" type="com.jmr.agency.banking.data.db.communication.CommTransaction" />
    </data>`

    public class CommTransaction extends CommAgent
                        implements Parcelable { 
        private Double txnAmount;
        private String transId; 
        // RefId 
        private String serverTxnId; 
        // CBS 
        private String dBranch; 
        private String cBranch;
        private String dAccountNo; 
        private String dName; 
        private String dLoc; 
        private String dCurrency
    }
```

Comment: This is my model pojo   public class CommTransaction extends CommAgent implements Parcelable {

    private Double txnAmount;

    private String transId; // RefId

    private String serverTxnId; // CBS

    private String dBranch;

    private String cBranch;

    private String dAccountNo;

    private String dName;

    private String dLoc;

    private String dCurrency;

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32683129/android-databinding-error-could-not-find-accessor#answer-32683130 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351048/databinding-error-could-not-find-accessor?rq=1#answer-43351121 it might help

Comment: Post your xml code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Error it seems that Android data-binding looking for getters before it looks at public fields. In your code no fields has getter and setter.
Please modify the CommTransaction class by adding getters and setters.
This will resolve your error.

Comment: It is there I did not mention entire pojo

Comment: all field's getter setter and parcelable too